# libtiff4 error with ROS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ros, libtiff

I am trying to compile a ROS-package from a friend with catkin under Ubuntu 14.04 and am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.49.0, needed by   
//usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.54.0
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFStripSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/local/lib/libcvd.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Advance'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have libcvd installed and also libtiff4-dev. Has anybody any idea, how to solve that issue?

Thanks a lot,

snow

EDIT: As suggest I include the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test)
set (test_VERSION "0.0.1")


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  test_core
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
)

find_package(tracker)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-DNDEBUG -DNTIMING -DNRUN_UNIT_TESTS -g -O0 -std=c++11")

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
)


include_directories (include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${tracker_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${TRIANGULATION_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include)

include_directories (SYSTEM
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

set (SOURCE
  src/test/main.cc
  src/test/rosbridge.cc
  src/test/core.cc
)

add_executable (test ${SOURCE})

target_link_libraries(test
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so
  ${OpenCV_LIBS}
  ${tracker_LIBRARIES}
  cvd
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${TRIANGULATION_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: Is the library linked with the executable? Please post the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt`, the problem is probably located in this file.

Comment: I edited my previous post and add the `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!

You have to link against the libtiff lib in your lib folder like this:

```
target_link_libraries(test
  .
  .
  .
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5  
  .
  .
  .
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just linking `cvd` seems to not work in your case.
CMake comes with the great `find_package` feature, though, so let's use it:

1. Add `find_package(CVD REQUIRED)` at the top of the file
2. Add `${CVD_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to `include_directories`
3. Replace `cvd` in `target_link_libraries` with `${CVD_LIBRARIES}`

This may not work immediately but throw an error like "FindCVD.cmake not found".  This is a script that searches your file system for the actual location of this library on your system and stores the paths to the variables used above.  Many libraries already bring such an file themselves, but if this is not the case you have to provide it manually.  In most cases you don't have to write this file yourself, though, as there is usually a bunch of open source projects, that already created such a file, which you can reuse (for example [here](https://code.google.com/p/btl-shuda/source/browse/trunk/CMakeModules/FindCVD.cmake)).  Just google "FindCVD.cmake" to find them.

Once you have this file:

1. Create a new subdirectory called "cmake" in your project and store the file there.
2. Add `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)` at the top of your `CMakeLists.txt` (before the `find_package` call!)

Now it should hopefully work :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and that very well explained answer. Unfortunately I am still getting the exact same error :-(

Comment: Hm, just a guess, but maybe you have to explicitly link against libtiff as well (using the same procedure like above).

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, therefore I tried to find a `FindLibTiff.cmake` file. The only one I found was this one here:
https://github.com/hobit03/OGS_PVS/blob/master/CMakeConfiguration/FindLibTiff.cmake
But then I am getting just the following error by trying to compile:
`CMake Error at test/cmake/FindLibTiff.cmake:10 (include):
 include could not find load file `

Comment: @snow: The LibFindMacros module used there is not part of cmake itself, but can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Tronic/cmake-modules). Simply store the file in the same directory as the Find*.cmake files.

Comment: I included the LibFindMacros module from [here](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/accb9f2fe8fd8f6a1e114adac5b15304b0e0012d/entry/cmake/Modules/LibFindMacros.cmake). Now I do not get any errors from the `FindLibTiff.cmake`, but still have the origin issue :-(

Comment: what do you think about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272497/linking-error-with-libopencv-highgui-so-under-ubuntu-14-04-strange-result-wit/29837433#29837433) ? Is that maybe the same issue what I have and it is not working under Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: To be honest, I can only guess from now on. It seems, that libtiff4 is problematic on Ubuntu 14.04. Can you maybe use libtiff5 instead?

Comment: I guess not, but I am trying to figure out a way around. If I found a solution I will post it